# Possible concurrency issue when tracking counter inside file in php

Tags: php

Every time my php script is called, I do the following to keep track of no. of times script is called:
1. open a plain text file
2. read integer from it
3. increment that value
4. Write back the value and close file.

I feel there should be concurrency issues with this approach when there are say 1000 simultaneous requests to that script. Some read/write should fail. But I am not able to reproduce any issue (It seems working fine with many requests).

Do I need to use any concurrency mechanisms?

Comment: It's a race condition - you probably just haven't had the exact right conditions to make one request trash another's update. You should be using file locking mechanisms to make sure each PHP process has exclusive use of the file while it's doing its update. But since it's just a hit counter, you'd at most lose a hit or two if there are any problems.

Comment: If you have "1000 simultaneous requests to that script", you're obviously using the wrong solution. You should probably use a server of some sort, maybe a SQL server.

Comment: If you want to stick with the file, get a lock on the file by getting the write access on the file when you read it.

Comment: Just lock the file. Remember, Murphy's Law, if anything can go wrong, it will. I remembered developing a chat program and storing conversations in text files, forgot to lock, it made a lot of mess in the conversation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a database table. Each time your script is called you insert a value. Yout get how many times the script has been called with mysql_num_rows() in PHP or you could create a cronjob that updates your text file once a day.

Using a table guarantees that all the script calls will be stored. That would not happen if the same text file is obtained at the same time and updated (yout would lose one hit).

Comment: Thanks. I extensively use mysql but my doubt was regarding file writing. I know using database is better solution but I am specifically thinking of race conditions in php.